# TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable (flask, sql)

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.x, flask

I want to create a dynamic URL where you can put any name, it will search that name in table called **autores** and **SELECT** their **id**, and then return that **autor.id**

I'm trying to run this:

```
@app.route('/<string:autor>')
def iniciarSesion(autor):
    autor_id = db.execute("SELECT id FROM autores WHERE autor = :autor", {"autor":autor}).fetchone[0]
    return autor_id
```

And **SQL Server** says:

> TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

How can I get **autor.id**?

Comment: You want `fetchone()[0]`.  You're missing the parentheses `()`.

Comment: Thank you very much!, it was much simpler than i thought. Now it work's!!